# Ionic v4: place Logo in center of ion-header

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

```
   <ion-header mode="ios">
     <ion-toolbar class="ion-no-padding" mode="ios" color="secondary">
      <ion-buttons mode="md" slot="start">
        <ion-button (click)="toggleMenu()">
         <ion-icon slot="icon-only" src="assets/icon/hamburger.svg"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>My Navigation Bar</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>
```

This works perfectly for the Ion title in the center. I want to add a logo to the center instead of the text. Tried adding ion-icon inside ion-title but it didn't work.

```
    <ion-title>
     <ion-icon slot="icon-only" src="assets/icon/logo.svg"></ion-icon>
    </ion-title>
```

Comment: I don't have time to investigate this at the moment but you will need to test any solution on ios and android because they both have different layouts. I suspect you might need to set `mode="md"` to force it to one design on both platforms, then use `ion-text-center`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use `ion-text-center` for the ion-title?

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-img src="../../assets/img/logo.png"></ion-img>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its prefared to put the logo inside a div and giv it a class name

```
.classname {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: transperent;
}
```

And now every thing should work normally but i think if you put this class for ion-toolbar even the ion-button will be put in center ..